# how to populate and array with a loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have a strings in column "C", starting at C2 (for example: Cat, Dog, Bird, etc...) and I don't know how many. So I am using a LRow function to find the last row with data. Currently, the last row is C63 but this is expected to be different if I run the subroutine next week or next month (Hence why I said "I don't know how many"). I want to create an array for example RTArr = Array("Cat", "Dog", "Bird", etc...) So... I was thinking something like:

```
Dim RTArr As Variant

LRow = r.End(xlDown).Offset(x, y).Row

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To LRow
        str = .Range("C" & i).Value
    Next i
End With
```

Can I populate the array with something like:

```
Dim RTArr As Variant

LRow = r.End(xlDown).Offset(x, y).Row

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To LRow
        ArrNum = (i - 1)
        str = .Range("C" & i).Value
        RTArr(ArrNum) = str
    Next i
End With
```

Or does this not work because of the unknown size of the array? Or do I have to use "amend" in the loop? Would I be better off using a "collection" in this case? Or going about it some other way? Can I simply set a range of cells as an array without needing to loop?

Comment: `RTArr = Range("C2:C" & LRow).Value` will give you a 2d array.

Comment: Do you want a 1D array or a 2D array? If 2D, SJRs solution eliminates the need for a loop. For a a 1D solution, you'd need to set the size of the array before using a loop to enter values into it.

Comment: @ARL - or `RTArr =Application.Transpose(Range("C2:C" & LRow).Value)` will give you a 1d array without looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare a dynamic array at first (without the size), you need to ReDim it to the needed size before populating it, which in your case will be the number of rows e.g. ReDim RTArr(numberofitems). Or use a two dimensional array ReDim RTArr(numbercolumns, numberrows).

**Remember that standard arrays begin at element 0, but you can define it however you like.**

**Remember that when inputting ranges into array Excel creates by default a two-dimensional array**

More advanced techniques are possible of course, you can do some more research about VBA arrays regarding those:

1) you could ReDim the array after each element added inside of the loop, but this is mostly useful for one dimensional arrays.

2) you could define a much bigger size of array than needed before populating it, populate it, and then shrink the array to the actual size needed.

3) note that when using two (or more) dimensions ReDim Preserve works only on the last dimension.

Pseudo code for the basic populating:

```
Dim arr() as Variant

'we know we want to populate array with 10 elements
ReDim arr(1 to 10)

    For i = 1 to 10

    'This part will insert the count from the loop into the count position in array
    ' eg. first element of array will be a 1, second a 2 etc. until 10
    arr(i) = i
    Next i
```

Comment: Ultimately... I think this is what I needed... Although my post wasn't clear because I tried to provide a simplified example of what I actually was doing. But I think I will need to loop through using for/next to populate the array.

Comment: Yes, populating with For Next is easy. To grab content of cells just use Cells(rowcounter, columncounter) e.g. to grab from column A, from second row: Cells(i + 1, 1). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Excel supports the `TEXTJOIN` function:

```
Sub Kolumn2Array()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim N As Long
    Dim RTArray
    Dim comma As String

    comma = ","
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range("C2:C" & N)

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        RTArray = Split(.TextJoin(comma, True, r), comma)
    End With

End Sub
```